# pull all elements in div right / left bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am looking to make my page responsive, added bootstrap and placed my two divs in a row, inside a fluid-container.

I tried adding pull right / float right to the left buttons, and pull left / float left to the right image and they are not moving.

Am I not using the correct classes ?

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 right" style="float-right">
                <div class="h1padding"></div>
                <a class = "h1" style="float-right" href="" id="introID"><b>INTRO</b></a>

                <div class="h1padding"></div>
                <a class = "h1" href="" id="OnSuerfaceID"><b>ON THE</b> <span class="light">SURFACE</span></a>

                <div class="h1padding"></div>
                <a class = "h1" href="" id="FromOilID"><b>FROM</b> <span class="light">ORE TO OIL</span></a>

                <div class="h1padding"></div>
                <a class = "h1" href="" id="EnvImpactID"><b>ENVIRONMENTAL</b> <span class="light">CARE</span></a>

                <div class="h1padding"></div>
                <a class = "h1" href="" id="MoreThanGasID"><b>MUCH MORE THAN</b> <span class="light">GASOLINE</span></a>

                <div class="h1padding"></div>
                <a class = "h1" href="" id="OneMoreID"><b>ONE MORE</b> <span class="light">THING</span></a>
                <br><br>
                <div class="h1padding"></div>
                <div class="h1padding"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8 left" style="float-left">
                <img src = "assets/images/white-leaf-bg.jpg" id="frame"/>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
a:link, a:visited {
        font-family: 'Gotham';
        text-align: right;
        color: white;
        background: #005870;
        border: none;
        padding: 15px;
        font-size: 2rem;
        margin-top: 10px;
        cursor: pointer;
        position: absolute;
        right: 65%;
        transition: .4s;
        text-decoration: none;
}


a:hover, a:active {
        font-size: 2.5rem;
        color: #005870;
        background: white;
        transition: .4s;
        text-decoration: none;
}


h1{
    font-family: Gotham-Bold;
    text-align: right;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: white;
    background: #005870;
    border: none;
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 2rem;
    margin-top: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    right: 65%;
    transition: .4s;
    text-decoration: none;
}

h1:hover {
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    color: #005870;
    background: white;
    transition: .4s;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

The image seems to be on the left (only other thing is to figure out how to center it vertically) but the buttons are still on the left.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Your inline style attribute requires a 'real' style property. This one is invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your style property is invalid.

```
<div class="col-md-8 left" style="float-left">
    <img src = "assets/images/white-leaf-bg.jpg" id="frame"/>
</div>
```

Should be:

```
<div class="col-md-8 left" style="float:left;">
    <img src = "assets/images/white-leaf-bg.jpg" id="frame"/>
</div>
```

Or using bootstrap's own classes:

```
<div class="col-md-8 pull-left">
    <img src = "assets/images/white-leaf-bg.jpg" id="frame"/>
</div>
```

Now for your *content* to be on the right/left side, the elements you use are inline, so they're affected by the `text-align` CSS property:

```
<div class="col-md-8 pull-left text-right">
    <img src = "assets/images/white-leaf-bg.jpg" id="frame"/>
</div>
```

External codepen with the examples above using bootstrap:

- https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZXvjJG

Comment: `col-md-8` +  `pull-left` together I don't think that it makes sense! Anyways a lot of things are going on in this code :)

Comment: Well, it's not my task to create sense in this code, i'm merely solving OP's issue here :).

Comment: When i try the pull-left bootstrap class, it places the entire div to the left of the buttons, is there any way i can make the div pull left, but make the elements (buttons) be pulled right inside the div?

Comment: Sure! add `text-right` to the class with the column

Comment: I've semi-misread the question, but i've updated the answer to be more conclusive.

Comment: I know @Roberrt just saying :)

Comment: Tried <div class="col-md-4 pull-left text-right" > and <div class="col-md-4 pull-left " style="text:right" > and the buttons are still being pulled to the left :(

Comment: No no, the class `text-right` should be added, don't use inline styles, and if you use them, use them properly, so: `style="text-align:right;"`

Comment: Sorry im not sure what im missing i saw the updated example, and i want mine to be besically the same as that but reversed, i tried col-md-4 pull-right text-right for class, and buttons are still on the left and i tried the inline style with the right syntax as above, still not sure what im missing, very sorry im not getting this guys >.<

Comment: Remove the pull-right / pull-left classes to stop the columns from moving, and remove the text-right / text-left classes to stop the text from moving.

Comment: It wasnt working because of my old sites a css...   position: absolute;
   right: 65%; Removed those and now its perfect :) Thanks for all the help, much appreciated, im mainly a c# guy so all this web stuff is very new to me

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pull right to a `<div>` which you first place in the row.

There are ways to do it, but its not recommended and not the bootstrap way.

All you can do it will just adding classes to your HTML.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8" style="border:3px solid red">
      <img src="https://dncache-mauganscorp.netdna-ssl.com/thumbseg/23/23636-bigthumbnail.jpg" id="frame" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4" style="border:3px solid blue">
      <div class="h1padding"></div>
      <a class="h1" style="float-right" href="" id="introID"><b>INTRO</b></a>

      <div class="h1padding"></div>
      <a class="h1" href="" id="OnSuerfaceID"><b>ON THE</b> <span class="light">SURFACE</span></a>

      <div class="h1padding"></div>
      <a class="h1" href="" id="FromOilID"><b>FROM</b> <span class="light">ORE TO OIL</span></a>

      <div class="h1padding"></div>
      <a class="h1" href="" id="EnvImpactID"><b>ENVIRONMENTAL</b> <span class="light">CARE</span></a>

      <div class="h1padding"></div>
      <a class="h1" href="" id="MoreThanGasID"><b>MUCH MORE THAN</b> <span class="light">GASOLINE</span></a>

      <div class="h1padding"></div>
      <a class="h1" href="" id="OneMoreID"><b>ONE MORE</b> <span class="light">THING</span></a>
      <br><br>
      <div class="h1padding"></div>
      <div class="h1padding"></div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```